# How can I prevent Google Chrome v18 from auto-moving any bookmark I move onto the top toolbar?

Tags: google-chrome

[image]

As shown above, I'm trying to move the UW Libraries Proxies Bookmarklet to the left part of the bookmarks.

[image]

But then the program auto-shifts the bookmarklet back to where it was originally. It's apparently related to Chrome Sync, but I want to keep the Chrome Sync feature. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: v18 is a beta version. Beta version == bugs. File a bug report. I can't simulate this.

Comment: It turns out to be related to Chrome Sync actually now. But I want to keep my Sync feature.

Comment: I can confirm this issue on Chrome 17.0.963.79 3.0.0-12-generic

Comment: @JohannesM I have exactly same version but i am using Chromium and this bug is missing.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been reported since Aug 2009 at http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=20011 . You are right to note that the problem is due to Google Chrome Sync. Currently, `Sync` does not support arbitrary positioning of nodes, which is reported in this issue http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=145412

The scheduled fixed date for the latter bug is for Release 26, 11 Feb 2013.

In order to ensure the bugs get higher priority within the Chromium development team, I suggest starring both issues.